# Need help with a uniform continuity question

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $n^x$ is uniformly continuous over any bounded subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  I was originally trying to invoke the set being compact; however, I feel confident that that was going down the wrong path as say, $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, is not closed.  Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. $n^x=e^{x\lg n}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, hence uniformly continuous on any bounded and closed (i.e. compact) subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
2. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, and $B\subset A$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B$.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$,$B\subset A$,

then $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$, such that $\forall x,y\in A, |x-y|<\delta\tag{1},$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Then $\forall x,y\in B, |x-y|<\delta$, since $B\subset A$, we know condition $(1)$ is satisfied, hence $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. In particular, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B$ by definition.

3. Any bounded subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is there an $\epsilon$, $\delta$ proof that stems from that, or is it all just exposition?

Comment: @user102830 I think the proof for 1 can be found in any elementary analysis book, i.e. $f\in C[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. For 2 and 3, just proof by definition.

Comment: I have the proofs for 1 and 3 down, just having trouble with 2.  The book I'm using doesn't address that at all.  I understand the definitions, just can't link them up.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user102830 I have added more details.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I see it now.  Again, thanks!!